# Schedule camel timer to run in 2servers at a time

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where my application job must trigger every 10min which I configured using camel timer. Now the issue is this bundle is running in two different servers and both trigger same time as well.. is there a way to manage the timer in both servers so that it will not run at same time and do it periodically?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Camel master endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/master-component.html)?

Answer (score 0):

A very minimalist but often sufficient solution would be to use the `delay` option (for setting an initial delay before the first trigger) of [Camel Timer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html).

Calculate a random initial delay on startup according to your period. In your case a random delay between 0 and 10 minutes and set it as delay.

However, with "bad luck" they can still start very close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more effective to use Camel Quartz instead of Camel Timer on burki solution, the cron mask will be more effective.
For a robust solution, you should look at [idempotency](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html) but it takes time to set up.